# Is it safe to have firebase keys on a users local machine?

Tags: firebase, electron

I'm trying to create an electron app, and I decided to use firebase (email/password) for authentication. Right now, the app directly sends the request to login via `firebase.auth().loginWithEmailAndPassword` and thus the app also has the API keys stored. If someone were to decompile /reverse engineer / investigate HTTP requests with this app, would it be possible to get the API key and create users as they please.

The only solution I thought of was proxying everything behind another server that takes care of more logic, is this the only way to prevent something like this?

Comment: I am working on a similar project, but worried about a different API key. I actually decided to scrap the Electron approach for the very reason that if the API key is in the application, and the application is on someone's PC, that someone has access to the API key. 

Are you sending the API key to the server using an HTTP request? If so, tools like Fiddler or Wireshark can easily present the API key to someone looking for it.

I'm not posting this as an answer because I'd like to see what information others have to provide on this topic.

Comment: Robert, did you find a solution?

Comment: @vaibhavS Instead of using firebase, I just hosted a remote websever and hosted a database by myself (and just sent a request to that server instead of to firebase).  Still not sure if giving the user the API key is secure (or what the correct process to use firebase in that case would be).